# dig: couldn't get address for 'ns2.bluedental.pl': not found. Linux DNS server

Tags: debian, bind

I have my own DNS server.

Web browsers shows `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` for my sites.

My external IP is `37.190.144.15`

For example I have `cloud.bluedental.pl` domain.

When I type `dig cloud.bluedental.pl`  from server, everything works

But when I make `dig cloud.bluedental.pl` from external network I got `NXDOMAIN` Error.

When I check `dig cloud.bluedental.pl @37.190.144.15` everything works again.

But if I type `dig cloud.bluedental.pl @ns2.bluedental.pl`, the output is: `dig: couldn't get address for 'ns2.bluedental.pl': not found`

**cloud.bluedental.pl bind config file:**

```
$TTL 86400
@ IN SOA cloud.bluedental.pl. marcin.bluedental.pl ( 2019071000 10800 15 604800 10800 )
@ IN NS ns2.bluedental.pl.
ns2 IN A 37.190.144.15
@ IN A 37.190.144.15
www IN A 37.190.144.15
```

**cloud.bluedental.pl zone:**

```
zone "cloud.bluedental.pl" IN {
    type master;
    allow-transfer {none;};
    file "/var/named/dns.cloud.bluedental.pl.conf";
};
```

**Bind options:**

```
acl mynetwork {
    172.19.0.0/10;
    192.168.1.0/24;
    localhost;
};

options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";


    allow-recursion { mynetwork; };
    allow-transfer { none; };
    allow-update { none; };

    forwarders {
             8.8.8.8;
             84.200.69.80;
             8.26.56.26;
    };

    dnssec-validation auto;
    version "Bluedental DNS2 server";
    hostname none;
    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
    server-id none;
};
```

Two weeks ago these configurations worked well for many months. I don't know why now it's not working

Comment: Are you also the owner of the parent `bluedental.pl` domain, or is it managed by different people?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the domain is *not delegated* to your DNS server, because there is no "NS" record for it in the parent 'bluedental.pl' domain. As a result, other resolvers have no way of knowing that they need to ask your DNS server about this domain.

This is where the NS chain ends:

```
$ dnstracer -s. cloud.bluedental.pl
Tracing to cloud.bluedental.pl[a] via A.ROOT-SERVERS.NET, maximum of 3 retries
A.ROOT-SERVERS.NET [.] (2001:0503:ba3e:0000:0000:0000:0002:0030)
 |\___ c-dns.pl [pl] (93.190.128.146)
 |     |\___ ns3.nazwa.pl [bluedental.pl] (77.55.127.10)
 |     |\___ ns2.nazwa.pl [bluedental.pl] (77.55.126.10)
 |      \___ ns1.nazwa.pl [bluedental.pl] (77.55.125.10)
[...]
```